# Slow execution of sas program in sasgrid platform

Tags: unix, sas, netezza

I use Unix sas in executing the sas code using sasplex platform.there is always a need to upload huge records into netezza database.i use the following script to connect/upload data into to netezza-

```
Connect to netezza (user=s password=m server=192.168.54.32 database=test connection=global)
```

It takes hardly `5mins` to upload `5gb` data in `sasplex platform(sasplex)`

But, recently moved from `sasplex to sasgrid` plateform with same `netezza` string.but now execution time of sas program is very low.it takes 5 hours to upload to the above mentioned data(sasgrid). I also tried to include `insert buff time` in string but impact is very less.

Could you please help us how execution time of sas program can do faster.

Problem only database.rest are same.

Comment: there are a lot of things that could be going on here.  things like differing system options to connectivity differences.  your best bet to get this resolved is to call (or email) SAS Technical Support.

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you have SAS/ACCESS for Relational Databases installed, the fastest way to upload data into Netezza would be proc append with option BULKLOAD=YES - see:

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acreldb/63647/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003181092.htm

Example syntax:

```
libname sasflt 'SAS-data-library';
libname net_air netezza user=louis pwd=fromage
        server=air2 database=flights;

proc sql;
create table net_air.flights98
       (bulkload=YES bl_options='logdir "c:\temp\netlogs"') 
        as select * from sasflt.flt98;

proc append base=net_air.allflights
 (BULKLOAD=YES
  BL_DATAFILE='/tmp/fltdata.dat'
  BL_USE_PIPE=NO
  BL_DELETE_DATAFILE=NO)
data=sasflt.flt98;
run;
```